# Divs take up all available height

Tags: html, css

I want to create three divs inside of one 'wrapper'-div. I want the three divs, let's call them 'left', 'center' and 'right', to be visible like three columns next to each other. The columns are shown in the right way, and the height takes up 100% of the screen, but when I add more text in the center div, I want the divs to take all available height of the screen. Like you see in the snippet below, ***the heights of the divs won't vertically stretch like I'd want them too***.

I tried changing the divs to table and table-cell display, but I couldn't get this to work. Besides that I tried messing around with position absolute and relative, but I couldn't get this to work either.

In the real situation the centered div takes up 1024px in width and the left and right divs have a width of 50%-512px.

I searching for a way to solve this but I still couldn't get it to work.

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 400px;
  }
div#menu{
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 600px;
  }
div#wrapper{
  
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  
  }
div#left{
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  }
div#center{
  width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  }
div#right{
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="menu">
      menu-item 1, menu-item 2, menu-item 3
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="left">
      </div>
      <div id="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eleifend tellus eget odio cursus, id dignissim dolor tincidunt. Maecenas libero quam, scelerisque tincidunt est sit amet, consequat faucibus massa. Fusce at varius nunc. Integer mattis velit purus, nec dignissim ipsum pulvinar eget. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse tempor, turpis eu convallis commodo, erat elit cursus sem, vel dignissim augue urna sit amet purus. Fusce accumsan risus neque, a dapibus velit mollis in. Aliquam varius euismod lorem sit amet bibendum. Donec tempus neque ac interdum pulvinar.

Nulla id iaculis magna. Ut dui lorem, porttitor eget volutpat vel, interdum at nibh. Duis rhoncus, eros ut pharetra euismod, metus metus elementum enim, id egestas sem arcu sit amet nisl. Quisque sed aliquam est. Vivamus bibendum sapien sit amet nisi auctor, et congue elit cursus. Praesent feugiat ex ex, in elementum augue efficitur a. Sed a felis ut est pharetra venenatis eu ac metus. Donec sed nisl semper, dignissim est ac, faucibus dolor. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Cras bibendum nulla dolor, et tincidunt ligula hendrerit ac.

Integer et tincidunt ante, tincidunt hendrerit lacus. Nullam viverra id enim et viverra. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean ullamcorper posuere pharetra. Nullam ac quam eu nisl vulputate condimentum quis eu ante. Mauris vel egestas tortor. Ut suscipit ex ac commodo pharetra. Sed pharetra convallis ornare. Curabitur posuere dictum sapien, et rutrum nulla tempor sit amet. Nulla sagittis massa quis vulputate vehicula. Proin dignissim lorem vel neque finibus, ut sodales dolor sollicitudin. Maecenas finibus leo non lorem porttitor condimentum. Aenean nec odio id nulla scelerisque bibendum.

Fusce feugiat sem turpis, id iaculis dui condimentum vel. Vivamus tempus semper ultricies. Vestibulum egestas viverra blandit. Nunc leo justo, semper ut elit in, luctus pharetra nibh. Cras ac lectus egestas quam interdum vehicula. Vivamus pulvinar sapien sed gravida pharetra. Mauris hendrerit congue augue, quis vulputate mauris vulputate at. Nulla sit amet ullamcorper ante.

In lobortis sem id arcu dignissim pretium. Sed vulputate eleifend leo. Donec eget risus sit amet ante molestie porta. Phasellus massa diam, lacinia ac imperdiet ut, molestie vitae nisl. Pellentesque tristique ligula lacus, eu tempus est feugiat vitae. Ut ac tincidunt nunc. Nulla et lectus quam. Aenean auctor tempus nibh sed efficitur. Nam blandit dictum ligula bibendum mollis. Proin mollis lorem at viverra porttitor. Duis placerat bibendum libero, id vulputate quam posuere id. Vestibulum vel ex mollis, tempor tortor et, suscipit risus. In augue dui, bibendum et tempus id, hendrerit vitae sapien. Aliquam erat volutpat.
      </div>
      <div id="right">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://bitsofco.de/holy-grail-layout-css-grid/ and http://alistapart.com/article/holygrail should get you started.  What you're looking for is considered the "holy grail" of layouts

Comment: This wasn't what I had in mind, I was thinking of a fixed center and flexible sides, but this is maybe even better. I'll look into it!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using flexbox? You could make them all the same height using something like this:

```
#wrapper{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
#left, #center, #right {
    display: flex;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rxdd4mdd/

#### Update:

I had a look at the website you posted a link to and you need to replace the folowing rules in your css, with these:

```
#profile-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
}

#profile-wrapper .left, 
#profile-wrapper .right {
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}

#profile-wrapper #profile-page {
    width: 1024px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

I've posted the full HTML of the edited page here: http://pastebin.com/9PvQvfiU

#### Update 2:

This should make sure that it is at least 100% of the height of the body:

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#profile-page {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: This looked good in the fiddle but for some reason it doesn't work on my website and messes everything else up as well.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of it?

Comment: Your edited post seems to work great except when the text on my profile page isn't that long, the divs arent on 100% of the screen anymore. http://www.zmo2017.nl/RanD/temp.php

Comment: Thanks for the second edit, I'm implemented it but I still can't get it to work.

Comment: Take a look at this [CSS-Tricks Complete Guide To Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) its a good start for understanding how the flexbox works

Answer (score 0):

Use Style Height :Auto; for wrapper div

```
#wrapper {
width: 600px;
height: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kn9spjhn/

Comment: @Grafit: check my answer

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but I can't get it to work on the website.

Comment: Hey @Grafit if you still struggling with your problem then just have a look this link : https://jsfiddle.net/9bhuejm9/6/  I have used you temporary page CSS and HTML to solve the problem :)